# Setting AKInput with a AKDevice

Tags: audiokit

I have a multi-channel mixer connected, and I want to setup a few AKInput's pointing to the specified AKDevice I got back from

```
let devices = AudioKit.inputDevices
```

but can't figure out how to go about that. I tried doing this

```
    let mic1 = AKMicrophone.init()

    do {
        try mic1.setDevice(devices![1])
        mic1.start()
    } catch {
        print("failed device")
    }
```

though it doesn't appear any audio is there.